# SQL Servr : insert into table from a tabular Excel table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Excel file with the following data:

[image]

I need to insert this data into a SQL Server table but in list form.

Example:

[image]

So I have to transform the tabular format from Excel and have only 3 columns:

```
degreeant, positionant, amount
```

Any clue?

Comment: Cut n Paste?  It doesn't look like many columns from here...

Comment: I posted an answer recently that deals with this kind of thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983881/python-excel-matrix/47984626#47984626

Comment: What does 35.51 represent?

Answer (score 0):

You import your data into SQL Server using your favourite tool (SSIS?) into a staging table that has the same structure of the excel file. 
Then, you append the data to the target table with the query:

```
insert into TargetTable(degreeant, positionant, Amount)
SELECT degreeant, 0 as Positionant, Positionant_0 from StagingTable
union all 
SELECT degreeant, 1 as Positionant, Positionant_1 from StagingTable
union all 
SELECT degreeant, 2 as Positionant, Positionant_2 from StagingTable
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the excel data to tab separated file. Then put each line in an array. After that take the necessary ones with array element number. And write your database query to insert.

```
file = open(“tsf”, “r”)  //tab seperated file is read
//open db connection here
for line in file:  
    array = line.split("\t")
    //insert necessary elements of b with query here
    // eg. insert into table values(array[0], array[2], array[4]) 
    pass
//close db connection
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do it and simple with Excel with Unpivot table

[image]

Select all the columns you want to Unpivot

[image]

Click on the Unpivot button

[image]

And voila!!!

[image]